# Move CI database to wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress

How can i move my existing database of Code Igniter to Word press? I am able to import data in csv and sql format or other formats available in PHP Myadmin....and i want to move this data to word press database for one of the custom post types

I have searched for plugins related to it like csv import, all in one csv import, but couldn't resolve this issue.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-csv-importer/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-csv/

Comment: Isn't Code Igniter a framework? You want to *move* a *database* from a framework to a blog software? Please take a minute an rethink what you're trying to do / ask.

Comment: Yes, I have my site existing site in CI and i am revamping it to word press...so is there a way i can move its data as well